# Emoji NSTextStorage

Tags: regex, ios7, emoji, nstextstorage

I'm currently working on a custom NSTextStorage on iOS, I require to detect some hashtags (#), mentions and urls... All work fine at this point, but if user tries to input a emoji char from keyboard isn't displayed, because I'm using Helvetica font.

I'm using a regular expresión to detect hashtags, mentions and urls in this way:

```
NSRegularExpression *iExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                             options:0
                                                                               error:NULL];

NSRange paragraphRange = [self.string paragraphRangeForRange: self.editedRange];        

[iExpression enumerateMatchesInString:self.string
                              options:0
                                range:paragraphRange
                           usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    // Changing format of match
}
```

Where `pattern` is a valid regex pattern to find hashtags, urls or mentions.

Are there some pattern to detect emoji chars? what pattern should I use, I had tried this (and many others) `[^\\x{1F601}-\\x{1F64F}\r\n]`without success.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iOS programming regex patterns, but what I'm sure about is, although you are pointing to the correct range, you are excluding a character set rather than including by using a caret sign `^` within a character set `[]` definition. Also I don't think you have to escape those hex points and match for CRs & LFs.

There is a complete Emoji Unicode table consisting of their corresponding Unicode points [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) that I gathered in a single line expression below:

```
([0-9#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?
```

In a PCRE flavor enabling `UTF-16` flag is a must by typing `u` in modifiers part to match unicode characters, so it would be `/ABOVE-EXPRESSION/u` but unfortunately I don't know how it is done in your specific case.